# Can anyone update npm on the VS Code Terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I have recently updated npm on my cmd prompt in order to use yarn package manager. I want to be able to use yarn with Visual Studio Code, but I can not get the terminal in Visual Studio Code to update npm past v8.3.0

I've tried:

- `npm install`
- `npm install -global npm@latest`
- `npm install -g npm`
- `npm i -g npm`
- `npm update`
- `npm update npm`
- `npm update -g npm`
- `npm update -global npm@latest` (this command actually downgraded npm to 8.1.2)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You do not need to update it in the VSCode terminal to update it, VSCode just has a built in UI for your terminal emulators, and is not any different.  So I don't know why you're trying in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install n which is a package that lets you quick switch node version.
Install it with

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

Once installed you can select the preferred version

```
sudo n 8.3.0
```

**REFERENCE**: https://github.com/tj/n#installing-nodejs-versions